# NCAlgebra: how to set distributivity?

Tags: ncalgebra

Is the non-commutative product in NCAlgebra also not distributive? From the documentation it seems it should be. But here is an expression, that it does not seem to be able to simplify:

```
SetNonCommutative[A, B];
SetCommutingOperators[C1];
Commutator[x_, y_] = x ** y - y ** x;
SetCommutators = {Commutator[A, B] :> 1};
G1 = Commutator[A, B + C1];
NCReplaceAll[G1, SetCommutators]
(* A ** (B + C1) - (B + C1) ** A *)
```

However this should be simplified to 1, since the commutator $[A,B]=1$ and $[A,C1]=[B,C1]=0$.

On the other hand the bare commutator can be simplified correctly:

```
SetNonCommutative[A, B];
SetCommutingOperators[C1];
Commutator[x_, y_] = x ** y - y ** x;
SetCommutators = {Commutator[A, B] :> 1};
G1 = Commutator[A, B];
NCReplaceAll[G1, SetCommutators]
(* 1 *)
```

The behaviour in the first case is also obtained with a number instead of C1:

```
SetNonCommutative[A, B];
SetCommutingOperators[C1];
Commutator[x_, y_] = x ** y - y ** x;
SetCommutators = {Commutator[A, B] :> 1};
G1 = Commutator[A, B + 1];
NCReplaceAll[G1, SetCommutators]
(* A ** (1 + B) - (1 + B) ** A *)
```

So either the operation `**` is not distributive or I am really confused why NCAlgebra can not simplify this expression. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

**Formulated as a simple question: how can I get NCAlgebra to simplify the expression in the first code snippet to 1?**

Comment: If it's relevant: I am using NCAlgebra 5.0.4 with Mathematica 12.0.

Comment: Just use `Distribute` on `**` or add an `UpValue` to `NonCommutativeMultiply`

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks! I’d be happy to accept that as an answer if you provide a code snippet that works! And maybe a short explanation of why this is necessary (I thought for example that ** is distributive by default, but according to your comment that seems to be not the case)

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica does not have an automatic distributive property and for a good reason. If it existed it would be impossible to collect or simplify expressions into products of sums. In order to trigger the distributive property you should use the `Expand` function. For example, the following expression in Mathematica

```
(A + B) C - A (C + B C/A)
```

remains as written above. However,

```
(A + B) C - A (C + B C/A) // Expand
```

evaluates to `0`.

Likewise, NCAlgebra has `NCExpand`, which in your case can be used in

```
NCReplaceAll[NCExpand[G1], SetCommutators]
```

to produces the desired value of `1`.